# Github Actions: using custom secret v GITHUB_TOKEN

Tags: github, github-actions

I've read several tutorials and [the docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/security-hardening-for-github-actions) for adding secrets. This is what confuses me:

- If you go to `github.com/username/repo -> Settings->Secrets->Actions`

You can create a secret, which apparently you could reference from that repo using `${{ secrets.MYSEC }}`. For me as a user at least (not an org) this does not work well.

After reading the last lines of the docs:

> If you need a token that requires permissions that aren't available in the GITHUB_TOKEN, you can create a personal access token and set it as a secret in your repository

I think the problem is that the tokens created on the repo don't have enough privileges/can't authenticate me, for some reason.

Can you explain why? Is this detailed somewhere? What am I misunderstanding about the environment secret?

- What I normally do is

  - Create a personal access token with the right permissions
  - or use GITHUB_TOKEN which is normally enough

Comment: Docs are here: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication#permissions-for-the-github_token You can always compare SHA of secret from CI with sha of value you set in github secret like: `echo -n "${{ secrets.MYSECRET }}" | sha1sum`

Comment: @piotrekkr that is not the question. The issue is that you can create Secrets in your repo, and those won't work. Only PATs work.

Comment: After reading your question, there is one point that is not clear to me. Do you want to use repository "global" secrets or repository "environment" secrets?

Comment: @Minsky What does not work exactly? You did not clarify what you are actually trying to do and you don't have permissions. Is it checkout operation? Is it GitHub API call? Something else? What permission do you need that cannot be set on GITHUB_TOKEN? Most of permission can be set on GITHUB_TOKEN but not all. Fine grained permission list for PAT can be found [here](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/permissions-required-for-fine-grained-personal-access-tokens)